# Some API's -MkParseDisplayNameEx, ADsGetObject- are not working well for LDAP on "windows server 2008 64bit"

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, ldap

I have this code that is running in all windows platforms (XP 32bit, XP 64bit, server 2003 32bit, server 2008 32bit, windows 7 32bit), I just can't run it on "windows server 2008 R2 64bit" the API causes an exception that can't be handled:

"Application defined exception (code 0x0eedfade) at 0x7773c42d"

and this is the code I used:

```
function GetObject(APath: String): IDispatch;
var
  Moniker: IMoniker;
  Eaten: integer;
  BindContext: IBindCtx;
  Dispatch: IDispatch;
begin
  Result := nil;
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, BindContext));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayNameEx(BindContext, PWideChar(WideString(APath)), Eaten, Moniker));
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindContext, nil, IUnknown, Dispatch));
  Result := Dispatch;
end;
```

the exception appears in this line :

```
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayNameEx(BindContext, PWideChar(WideString(APath)), Eaten, Moniker));
```

I Also tried this code but also an none-handled exception appears:

```
function GetObject(APath: String): IDispatch;
begin
  ADsGetObject(APath, IDispatch, Result);
end;
```

I am passing the same APath parameter in all platforms:
"LDAP://MYDOMAIN/CN=MY_DOMAIN_GROUP,CN=Users,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM"

This is related to the LDAP protocol and the ADSIEdit.dll library, I checked if the RSAT -Reamote Server Administration Tool- which supposed to install this library and it looks that this windows component is installed already...Any idea for the cause of this exception?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you build the same program with Visual Studio in C++?